# Subalgebras of a polynomial ring carved out by (families of) coefficient equalities

Tags: polynomials, power-series, symmetric-functions, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $\mathbf{k}$ be a field, and let $P=\mathbf{k}\left[  x_{1},x_{2}
,\ldots,x_{n}\right]  $ be a polynomial ring over $\mathbf{k}$ in $n$
variables $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$. Alternatively, $P$ can be a power series
ring, or $n$ can be $\infty$.

A "monomial" shall mean a monomial in $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$. For each
monomial $\mathfrak{m}$ and each $f\in P$, we let $\left[  \mathfrak{m}
\right]  \left(  f\right)  $ denote the coefficient of $\mathfrak{m}$ in $f$.

Fix a scalar $c_{\mathfrak{m}}\in\mathbf{k}$ for each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$.

Let $S$ be a set of pairs of monomials. Let $M$ be the subset
\begin{align}
\left\{  f\in P\ \mid\ c_{\mathfrak{m}}\cdot\left[  \mathfrak{m}\right]
\left(  f\right)  =c_{\mathfrak{n}}\cdot\left[  \mathfrak{n}\right]  \left(
f\right)  \text{ for all }\left(  \mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\right)  \in
S\right\}
\end{align}
of $P$. It is clear that $M$ is a $\mathbf{k}$-vector subspace of $P$.

> **Question.** What are examples of choices of $c_{\mathfrak{m}}$ and $S$ for
> which $M$ is a $\mathbf{k}$-subalgebra of $P$ ?

Here are three examples where this is satisfied:

**Example 1.** Let $c_{\mathfrak{m}}=1$ for each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$. Let
$S$ be the set of all pairs $\left(  \mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\right)  $ of
monomials such that $\mathfrak{n}$ is obtained from $\mathfrak{m}$ by a
permutation of the variables. Then, $M$ is the ring of symmetric polynomials
in $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ over $\mathbf{k}$; this is a $\mathbf{k}
$-subalgebra of $P$.

**Example 2.** Let $c_{\mathfrak{m}}=1$ for each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$. Let
$S$ be the set of all pairs $\left(  \mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\right)  $ of
monomials such that $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ are pack-equivalent
(i.e., we can write $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ in the forms
$\mathfrak{m}=x_{i_{1}}^{a_{1}}x_{i_{2}}^{a_{2}}\cdots x_{i_{k}}^{a_{k}}$ and
$\mathfrak{n}=x_{j_{1}}^{a_{1}}x_{j_{2}}^{a_{2}}\cdots x_{j_{k}}^{a_{k}}$,
where $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{k}$ are positive integers and $i_{1},i_{2}
,\ldots,i_{k},j_{1},j_{2},\ldots,j_{k}$ are elements of $\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $ satisfying $i_{1}<i_{2}<\cdots<i_{k}$ and $j_{1}
<j_{2}<\cdots<j_{k}$). Then, $M$ is the ring of quasisymmetric polynomials in
$x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ over $\mathbf{k}$; this is a $\mathbf{k}
$-subalgebra of $P$.

**Example 3.** Let $c_{\mathfrak{m}}=2^{\ell\left(  \mathfrak{m}\right)  }$
for each monomial $\mathfrak{m}$, where $\ell\left(  \mathfrak{m}\right)  $
denotes the number of distinct variables that appear in $\mathfrak{m}$. (For
example, $\ell\left(  x_{3}^{5}x_{4}x_{7}^{2}x_{8}\right)  =4$.) Let $S_{1}$
be the set $S$ from Example 2. Let $S_{2}$ be the set of all pairs $\left(
\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}\right)  $ of monomials, where $\mathfrak{m}
=x_{i}^{2}\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{n}=x_{i}x_{i+1}\mathfrak{p}$ for some
$i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $ and some monomial $\mathfrak{p}$ that
contains neither of the variables $x_{i}$ and $x_{i+1}$. (For example,
$\left(  x_{1}^{3}\underline{x_{2}^{2}}x_{5}^{4},x_{1}^{3}\underline{x_{2}
x_{3}}x_{5}^{4}\right)  \in S_{2}$, where the underlining merely marks the
$x_{i}^{2}$ and $x_{i}x_{i+1}$ parts of the monomials.) Let $S=S_{1}\cup
S_{2}$. Then, $M$ is a $\mathbf{k}$-subalgebra of $P$. (This is more or less
the $\mathbf{k}$-subalgebra $\operatorname*{span}\left(  \overline
{K}_{n,\Lambda}\right)  _{n\in\mathbb{N};\ \Lambda\subseteq\left[  n\right]
}$ constructed in Theorem 4.4 **(a)** of my [*The eta-basis of
QSym*](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/etabasis.pdf),
except that I am now working in finitely many variables.)

Example 1 is trivial to check; Examples 2 and 3 are easiest to verify by
finding bases of the respective subspaces $M$ and showing that products of two
elements of these bases expand as linear combinations of these bases. As an
offshoot of a project I proposed, a student is looking for some general
criteria that ensure that $M$ is a $\mathbf{k}$-subalgebra of $P$; the
question above is meant to gather a few more examples to experiment upon.